# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows>= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql

Subquery returned more than 1 value error. How to solve this?

```
SELECT top 1 address
FROM tblAdr A
WHERE A.pkey=
  (SELECT b.pkey FROM tblMachine b WHERE b.ADDRESS_PKEY IS NULL
  )
```

Comment: either use `IN` or better a `JOIN`

Answer (score 2):

The subquery (the quantity in parentheses) is returning more than one `pkey` value, which isn't allowed because a single scalar value is required.  If you are content with checking whether a `pkey` in `tblAdr` matches *any* of the values in the subquery, then you can use `WHERE A.pkey IN (...)` as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 1 address
FROM tblAdr A
WHERE A.pkey IN (SELECT b.pkey FROM tblMachine b WHERE b.ADDRESS_PKEY IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `=` to an `IN`

```
select top 1 address from tblAdr A where A.pkey in (select b.pkey from tblMachine b where b.ADDRESS_PKEY is null)
```

This should fix the error, however the logic of your query is likely flawed. You are after one row only (`select top 1`), however you don't define what row should be chosen first (no `order by` clause).

Answer (score 0):

Use `IN` instead of `=` as your subquery returns multiple matching rows.

```
SELECT top 1 address
FROM tblAdr A
WHERE A.pkey IN
  (SELECT b.pkey FROM tblMachine b WHERE b.ADDRESS_PKEY IS NULL
  );
```

Also, always use top queries with order by.

Answer (score 0):

This subquery "select b.pkey from tblMachine b where b.ADDRESS_PKEY is null" returns multiple value which you can't compare with "=" operator.but you want this try in clause